# Extract resources from a SFS file

Tags: reverse-engineering

I would like to extract resources from a resources file which magic key is SFS. I don't find any documentation about this file type nor any tools to extract resources from this file type. It's resources of a 1997 game.

Comment: yes it's http://www.abandonwarering.com/girlsab/doku.php?id=games:pc:xtet&s=xtet

Comment: Could it be one of these? http://www.computerfileextensions.com/file-extensions.php/SFS

Comment: @DarenW If only I knew. It's a mysterious...

Answer (score 1):

If it comes from Linux, the content of the sfs-file may be extracted with this tool:

http://www.sas1946.com/main/index.php?topic=7017.0

Otherwise have a look at: http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=17322