# Reading a tif file

Tags: image-processing

When I'm trying to open a tif file with typical image editors I get a message that the tif is corrupt, but it is not.

When I do in bash :
hexdump -c file.tif | head

I get :

0000000   S   F   S   0   1   e   -   �   �   �   z   �   e   3   � 216
0000010   �   S   j   �   W   o 205 021 215 006   � 024   E   �   -   S
0000020   X   �  \0 036 022   � 022   �   k   n 221   �   O 235 031   4
0000030   M   �   �  \0   h   �   �   j   �   J   � 232   �   �   �   ^
0000040 232   >   �   g 031   � 232   ,   W 206   u   z   @   �   6 210
0000050   �   �   k   � 022 220   b   � 026   } 202   �   �   &   m
0000060   �   � 001   T   ` 034 215   i 215 031   �  \n 222   �   0   �
0000070 202   � 215   �   �   t   �   �   B 210   �   W   �   � 236 221
0000080   /   � 237   b   O 213   a   �  \t   d 231   ;   ~   >   � 023
0000090   �   �   N 030   �   .   ! 033 026   �   C   E   ;  \b 231   ;

What does this mean? How to interpret this?

Comment: How do you know it is not corrupt? What application is able to open it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

All TIFF files begin with "II" or "MM" to indicate byte order as Intel or Motorola... yours looks kind of wrong...

If you are on Linux or OSX, try "file file.tif" to see what your system makes of it.

Here is a TIF file from my Mac using "od -xc file.tif"...

```
0000000      4949    002a    0008    0000    0015    00fe    0004    0001
           I   I   *  \0  \b  \0  \0  \0 025  \0 376  \0 004  \0 001  \0
```

Is it abandonwarering?

[Extract resources from a SFS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409591/extract-resources-from-a-sfs-file)

Mmmm... ok it is not a straightforward TIF and not a standard SFS file. I would try running:

```
od -x  yourfile   | egrep "4949|4d4d"
```

to see if you find the start of a TIFF file with Intel or Motorola byte ordering. If you do, calculate the offset from the first column, and use that as an offset into "dd". So, if the offset is 512 bytes, I would do

```
dd if=yourfile of=test.tif bs=512 iseek=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, bash gives me back : 2007_4_10.tif: data .

Comment: Well, it would give TIF file if it thought it was a TIF... so I am saying it agrees that your file is corrupted.

Comment: I could guarantee it's not, it's used by a game to handle graphics for a character.

Comment: I understand that it might not be a tif file, but I can guarantee that this file is being used by a program to display graphics.

Comment: It's not abandonwavering, it's a small game I bought a while ago http://www.gazetamatematica.net/. I've also tryed using sfs extractors but it did not work.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I would vote your answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: After doing od -x  yourfile   | egrep "4949|4d4d" I get
 0000560 8489 1b0f 3738 4d4d c985 cd2e bc20 6a7d . How could I calculate the offset byte in this case? Still not sure what od -x does even tough i got it's man page.

Comment: It's on 24th line, 5th collumn. How does one define the offset ?

Comment: @shooting-squirrel, you start with the address at the beginning of the line, 0000560. It's an octal number. Now you count out to the start of the found pattern, in this case it starts at 566. Now convert from octal to decimal to get 374. (Hope you didn't read this when I showed hex instead of octal).

Comment: Sorry that didn't work out - I have used the technique with great success to recover a friend's wedding photos from a corrupt memory card. You could try posting the file somewhere online and give us access to it - I may be able to read it for you. Else, you may just have to screen capture whatever the picture is while the game is running...